# Installing Wine 1.5: configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries

Tags: software-installation, wine

```
    Wine Installer v1.0

Warning !! wine binary (still) found, which may indicate
a (conflicting) previous installation.
You might want to abort and uninstall Wine first.
(If you previously tried to install from source manually, 
run 'make uninstall' from the wine root directory)

We need to install Wine as the root user. Do you want us to build Wine,
'su root' and install Wine?  Enter 'no' to build Wine without installing:
(yes/no) yes
Running configure...

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for cpp... cpp
checking whether gcc -m32 works... no
configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries.

Configure failed, aborting install.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I guess you use Ubuntu 12.04 x64 which now supports multi-architecture. In other words, on a 64-bit system you can build only Wine-x64 version. Building 32-bit Wine on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 seems too buggy as for now.

So just run this command:

```
./configure --enable-win64
```

Comment: Doesn't that build wine64 instead of wine? I can't run windows 32-bit programs with wine64.

Comment: nowadays wine requires `flex` and `bison` so `sudo apt install flex bison` first but yes this is the best answer.

Comment: @tatsu I am using the portable version of Wine since I do not have ```sudo privileges```. Is there a corresponding command to install ```flex``` for non sudos?

Answer (score 24):

As per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748092/108802

You need to install the gcc-multilibs.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
> ```
>
> Then [...] specifyiong a 32-bit host and passing 32-bit compilation
>   flags:
>
> ```
> ./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
> ```

Comment: In my case, this still resulted in a slew of unmet 32-bit dependencies that apt refused to install. I think it would be less of a headache to install virtual Linux machine for compiling 32-bit stuff.

Comment: This is a better answer, since sometimes wine64 is unable to run 32-bit applications

Answer (score 6):

try installing the 32 bits dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386
```

Comment: Visiting this thread 7 years after this answer was posted ... Ubuntu 20.04 (now a couple of years old) was receptive when installing lines 2 of 3 and 3 of 3.  As to line 1 of 3, the following output:  "*Package `ia32-libs` is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.  However the following packages replace it:  `lib32ncurses5`, `lib32z1`.*"  With lines 2 and 3, that was sufficient for `configure` to complete and give a list of additional *optional* dependencies and the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04.1 having 64 bit

- `sudo apt-get install flex`
- `sudo apt-get install bison`
- `./configure --enable-win64 --without-freetype`,
- `make`

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do installition linux "RedHat 6.4" after installing some of the packages like gcc,gcc-c++,flex,bison etc.

with below run on prompt:

```
./configure --enable-win64 --without-freetype

make

wine notepad++.exe
```

Comment: and, does that work in Ubuntu?